# How convert imageBase64 to type file, using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code in javascript to convert from base64string to type file, but unfortunatetly is not supported in IE, how can I change it with pure javascript compatible with IE, I'm running this on VUE JS framework.

```
async previewImageFromDatabase(imageURI) {
      this.imageData = imageURI
      this.database = 'disable'
      this.files = await this.base64ImageToFile(imageURI, 'backendImage.jpeg', 'image/jpeg')
      this.load(this.files, this.imageData)
    }

async base64ImageToFile(src, fileName, mimeType){
      let resource = await fetch(src);
      let buffer = await resource.arrayBuffer();
      return await new File([buffer], fileName, { type: mimeType });
    }
```

Comment: Are you using an await/async polyfil yet; or a transpiler like babel? I don't think IE has native support for [async functions or promises](https://caniuse.com/#search=prom)

Comment: That is optional I could change to promises.